# Collapse multiple rows with character variables -- SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that looks like the following:

| id | gender | race | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | [REDACTED] | 10,000 |
| 1 | [REDACTED] | 2054-5 | [REDACTED] |
| 2 | F | [REDACTED] | 50,000 |
| 2 | [REDACTED] | 2054-5 | [REDACTED] |

I am trying to collapse it by the id variable, such that I get this dataset

| id | gender | race | income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | M | 2054-5 | 10,000 |
| 2 | F | 2054-5 | 50,000 |

Normally, I would do the following:

```
select 
max(gender),
max(race),
max(income),
id
from
table
group by id
```

but gender, race, and income are not numeric so I can't do that. Is there a way to select the non-redacted answers? For reference, I am conducting this in Snowflake using SnowSql.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing the `'[REDACTED]'` value with null before the aggregation:

```
select max(CASE WHEN gender='[REDACTED]' THEN NULL ELSE gender END),
       max(CASE WHEN race  ='[REDACTED]' THEN NULL ELSE race   END),
       max(CASE WHEN income='[REDACTED]' THEN NULL ELSE income END),
       id
from table
group by id
```

For a tested solution, please update your post with the DBMS you're using.

Comment: Or, just `MAX(NULLIF(gender, '[REDACTED]'))`

Comment: Correct @MatBailie

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE or NULLIF @lemon's answer shows you how to use CASE here is how to use NULLIF

```
select max(NULLIF(gender,'[REDACTED]')) as gender,
       max(NULLIF(race  ,'[REDACTED]')) as race,
       max(NULLIF(income,'[REDACTED]')) as income,
       id
from table
group by id
```